# Podio Push Service

Tags: .net, podio

I need to create a data Sync Application using .Net that pulls data from Podio and put into SQL Server using Podio API. 
is it possible for the podio to push the data instead of application pulling the data ? I mean does podio triggers any push service that can tell what Item is created or Updated in particular App..

Answer (score 0):

Podio can notify you about changes happening with items/apps via webhooks.

Please read more on how it works https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks and  https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks

Comment: Yes I read about the Webhooks.
But I am more interested in Push Services that is describe here 
https://developers.podio.com/examples/push .
But when i get the Item through Podio API i don't find any "push" property as defined in this Article.

Answer (score 0):

Podio API offers a push service on several endpoints. The way to subscribe to those endpoints vary depending on the tools (SDK) you use.

E.g. in Javascript you would use the SDK like this

```
  podio.request('GET', `/user/status`).then((data) => {

    // this is the important bit
    podio.push(data.push).subscribe(this.onNotificationReceived)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`All is well, we've been subscribed!`
      }));

  })
```

I can see that the .net SDK has a [Subscription Service](https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/blob/a37311d388a23efeddaa8c9174e0ba866614b5ee/Source/Podio%20.NET/Services/SubscriptionService.cs) as well, but .net it's not really my domain of expertise and I can't tell you exactly how to use it.

Seems pretty straightforward looking at the signature though

```
  public async Task<int> Subscribe(string refType, int refId)
```

**note:** subscribing to `/user/status` will notify you of pretty much every movement that the current user is doing